# Derivative of vector-valued function expressed as a matrix-valued function multiplied by constant vector

Tags: calculus, matrices

I have found some somewhat similar questions but nothing seems to be quite the same as my problem, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have a scalar cost function:
\begin{equation} C(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{v}) = \frac{1}{2} ||f(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{v})||^2_2 \end{equation}

The function $f$ is a vector valued function that operates on a vector $f: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$

It can be written in terms of a matix-valued function multiplied by a vector:
\begin{equation} f(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{v}) = G(\boldsymbol{x}) \cdot \boldsymbol{v} \end{equation}

I can use the chain rule to get the equation $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} \cdot G(\boldsymbol{x})\cdot \boldsymbol{v}$

In my context the value of $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$ have been empirically acquired and my goal is to learn the best fit of $\boldsymbol{v}$ from this data (ideally from regression). Where I'm running into confusion is correctly representing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}$ and then determining if such a fit is mathematically feasible.

First I'm looking to take the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{x}$, in terms of $G$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$.

So far this has been my approach:
\begin{align}
f(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{v}) &= G(\boldsymbol{x}) \cdot \boldsymbol{v}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 G_{11}+ \ldots + v_n G_{1n} \\
\vdots \\
v_1 G_{m1}+ \ldots + v_n G_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}&=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \frac{\partial G_{11}}{\partial x_1}+ \ldots + v_n \frac{\partial G_{1n}}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & v_1 \frac{\partial G_{11}}{\partial x_p}+ \ldots + v_n \frac{\partial G_{1n}}{\partial x_p}\\
\vdots \\
v_1 \frac{\partial G_{m1}}{\partial x_1}+ \ldots + v_n \frac{\partial G_{mn}}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & v_1 \frac{\partial G_{m1}}{\partial x_p}+ \ldots + v_n \frac{\partial G_{mn}}{\partial x_p}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial G}{\partial x_p}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{v} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \boldsymbol{v} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \boldsymbol{v}
\end{bmatrix}_{np \times p}
\end{align}

Is there a more compact way to represent this or some further manipulation I could be exploiting here? And furthermore, can the derivative $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}$ therefore be expressed as an expression which is linear in either $\boldsymbol{v}$ or some transform of $\boldsymbol{v}$?